# Cakephp different classes for requests

Tags: php, extjs4, cakephp-2.0

I have an application in Cakephp. In my front-end, it only responses for one request and I have used usual CakeRequest() class, and in my back-end, as far as using extjs, I have defined another Request and Response Class for multi-requests and multi-responses. but I have problem in distinguishing between them. I mean where and when one of them is executed. the default cakephp index.php file for front-end is

```
$Dispatcher->dispatch(new CakeRequest(), new CakeResponse(array('charset' => Configure::read('App.encoding'))));
```

and for back-end is

```
$Dispatcher->dispatch(new TestRequestCollection(...
```

but I don't know the if clause between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To what if clause are you referring to?

CakePHP is not designed to use different request classes in the index.php. Not sure what you are doing here. You might want to go the same route I went with [Bancha](http://banchaproject.org/) and create a second frontend controller which does different a dispatching.